# Changing width of <audio> in IE10

Tags: html, internet-explorer-10

I can't adjust the width of the  tag using any of the normal HTML or CSS options. It changes the width in Chrome but not in IE.

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="../audio/2013-08-30.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Any help would be appreciated. If I can't change the width, any suggestions of a nice slimmed down audio player that requires very little on the users end?